# Создание zip архива без пути к папке в архиве

Tags: python, zip

Пишу код, который должен запаковать все файлы из указанной папки в архив, но когда выполняю код, в архиве появляется папка в которой лежат файлы, а мне нужно чтобы сразу в архиве появились файлы из папки, как можно исправить?

```
temp_dir = os.path.join('temp_captcha_folder')

with zipfile.ZipFile('CapMonster.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, True) as myzip:
        source = os.listdir('temp_captcha_folder')
        for source_folder in source:
            for root,dirs,files in os.walk(source_folder):
                for file in files:
                    path = os.path.join(root, file)
                    myzip.write(path)
                    print(path)
```

например:
CapMonster.zip/temp_captcha_folder/settings.json - архив в моем коде

CapMonster.zip/settings.json - то что мне над

temp_captcha_folder/settings.json - путь к файлу

Comment: Что-то код не соответствует описанию структуры ваших файлов. Например, в `source`  попадает список файлов из `temp_captcha_folder` , а не каталогов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя проблема в том, что ты используешь `os.listdir` для получения списка файлов в указанной папке, и затем ты пытаешься выполнить `os.walk` для каждого из этих файлов, **что является ошибкой**. Вместо этого ты должен использовать `os.walk` сразу для указанной папки. Вот исправленный код:

```py
import os
import zipfile

temp_dir = 'temp_captcha_folder'

with zipfile.ZipFile('CapMonster.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, True) as myzip:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(temp_dir):
        for file in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            arcname = os.path.relpath(path, temp_dir)  # Используй относительный путь
            myzip.write(path, arcname=arcname)
            print(path)
```